# Excel vba conditional formatting using dynamic color key

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, conditional-formatting, color-key

I'm trying to create an Excel macro that applies conditional formatting to a target column using the condition of cells in another column and the format of cells in yet another column (essentially a color key).

The color key is a single column chart with colored cells containing text in each row (e.g. blue cell with "blue" as the text).

The goal is to be able to change the fill colors or text in the color key and have the target cells automatically change to the new colors or condition without having to hardcode the new RGB through Excel's conditional formatting rules manager.

This would save a lot of time as there are a lot of colors, and they must be the exact RGB match.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub ColorCode()

'Applies conditional formatting to Input Chart using the Color Key

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ColorKey As Range

Set ColorKey = Worksheets(2).Range("C6:C19")

Dim kCell As Object
Dim lCell As Object
Dim mCell As Object

With Worksheets(2)
    For Each mCell In Worksheets(2).Range("Input[Duration1]")
        If mCell.Value <> "0" Then
            For Each lCell In Worksheets(2).Range("Input[Color1]")
                If lCell.Value <> "" Then
                    For Each kCell In ColorKey.Cells
                        If lCell.Value = kCell.Value Then
                            mCell.Interior.Color = kCell.Interior.Color
                            mCell.Font.Color = kCell.Font.Color
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
```

This loops through each of the cells in the columns and actually colors them in. The issue is all of the cells are colored to the condition of the last cell, so all of the colors are the same rather than each cell being formatted for its own condition.

Before adding `"application.screenupdating=false"`, I can see the colors flickering while it's looping, but they just won't stick. When I try to add **`"ByVal Target as Range"`** to my code, my macro disappears, and to be honest, even though I've looked this up I don't really understand what this means.

I'm new to VBA, and am pretty sure I'm missing something simple. I'd really appreciate any help with this!

**I'm marking this as answered - Here is the updated code!**

```
Sub getcol()

Dim rr As Range
Dim tg  As Range

    Set color_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"

        For Each rr In Range("colorkey")
            color_dict.Add rr.Text, rr.Interior.Color
        Next


        For Each rr In Range("input[color1]")
            rr.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = color_dict(rr.Text)

        Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure a nested loop is appropriate here - don't you only want to color the cell on the same row as mCell ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understanding the rule to decide what color the target cell should be from your description.

But in any case, you probably want to create a `dictionary` to store colors against a `text` key. And then use this dictionary to loop over your target range and set the color of the cell by reading the text in that target cell (??)

in the below, I assume the text to create the dictionary key is in the column next to range `color_key`. If the text you wish to read in to create the dictionary key is actually in the same column then remove the `offset` (or set it to 0 column offsets).

I assume that `color_key` and `target_Range` are named ranges in your excel sheets (somewhere).

```
Sub getcol()

Dim rr As Range
Set color_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 For Each rr In Range("color_key")
    color_dict.Add rr.Offset(0, 1).Text, rr.Interior.Color
 Next

 For Each rr In Range("target_Range")
    rr.Interior.Color = color_dict(rr.Text)
 Next

End Sub
```

The code `CELL.Interior.Color` returns an integer code that represents the cell fill color, as you mentioned you need the exact same color.

A dictionary `dict` works by reading in (key, value) pairs using the syntax `dict.Add key, value`. And returns value when it is passed the corresponding key: `dict(key)=value`.

Comment: The rule is if the text in the target cell matches text in a color key cell, then the target cell should take on the interior color of the color key cell. 

Yes! I think a dictionary will work quite well based on your description; however, I am getting a run-time error 457 "the key is already associated with an element of this collection". Thoughts on why this may be?

Comment: Update- I did not read through your notes clearly earlier. Because my key text is in the same column, I removed the "offset" from "color_dict.add rr.offset(0,1).text,rr.interior.color" and added "offset" to "rr.interior.color=color_dict(rr.text)" so the color would be applied to another column, and it worked beautifully. Thank you so much!!

Comment: When using a VBA dictionary if you try to add an item with key that is already associated with an item in the dictionary, VBA will error. But with careful error catching, this is common pattern to filter only unique items (it is much quicker and more flexible than other methods). Basically, you want to `resume next` `on error`.